# Installing Dovecot and Exim on CentOS 6.4

Tags: centos, exim, dovecot

I've been looking for some guides on setting up a secure `dovecot` and `exim` mail server setup on `CentOS 6.4`, however it seems there's nothing out there.

Does anyone know of any guides - or - if someone could push me in the right direction that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up a blog post titled: [How to Setup a Mail Server on CentOS 5](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/226/how-to-setup-a-mail-server-on-centos-5/#more-226). That post covers using Sendmail and Dovecot but all of the setting up of Dovecot should apply for Exim as well.

That article covers setting up the following:

#### Primary packages

- sendmail
- spamassassin
- milter-greylist
- GeoIP
- clamav
- spamassassin-milter
- clamav-milter
- dovecot

#### Addons to spamassassin

- SPF
- DKIM

#### Optional Extras

- spf-milter

If you see any issues please feed them back so that I can keep that article current and relevant.

Answer (score -1):

we recently wrote an article on [how to setup a simple mailserver with Exim and Dovecot on a CentOS 7 system](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/setup-a-mailserver-with-exim-and-dovecot-on-a-centos-7-vps/) which you may find helpful.

It does not cover the installation and configuration of spamassasin, though there's a follow up article on [how to setup opendkim with exim](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-opendkim-and-exim-on-a-centos-7-vps/) for digital signing of the emails.

hth

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.